# Extract patterns from a file and subtract the values received

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

This is the code I have so far

```
grep -i "start" logs.txt | awk '{print $3}'
grep -i "end" logs.txt | awk '{print $3}'
```

So if the values for the start is 10 and end is 30. How can I subtract this and get 20 as the output.

Sample file : logs.txt

```
start_value : 10
end_value : 30
start_value : 20
end_value : 50
```

desired output :

```
differance1 : 20
differance2 : 30
```

Comment: If you could let us know sample input and sample expected output in your post we could possibly do this with in single `awk` itself/.

Comment: Oh thank you so much sir .

Comment: Thank u guys . it is working . It is helpful

Comment: Your welcome Aakash, also try to select any answer(not now may be after sometime once we have all answers in this post) as a CORRECT answer so that it may be helpful for other folks too, keep learning keep enjoying, cheers

Comment: Can i get the explaination that @John1024

Comment: ok I did it @ RavinderSingh13

Comment: Sorry . What if the sample file had start_time=10:30:00 and end_time=10:45:00 . How can i get the time difference between them

Comment: I have edited the question . Can anyone help me out with this

Comment: @Aakashk.u.: You need to ask a new question. You cannot edit the existing one and ask a different one

Comment: I have rolled back the question because, on SO, it is really bad form to change a question in a way that makes your existing answers wrong.  As @Inian states, you should instead ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/start_value/{start=$NF} /end_value/{print "difference"++i" : " $NF-start;start=""}' Input_file
```

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk '
/start_value/{  start=$NF                            } ##Searching for a string start_value in current line if found creating variable named start with value $NF.
/end_value/  {  print "difference"++i" : " $NF-start;  ##Searching for a string end_value and then printing string difference with variable i increasing value and printing the different of $NF and start variable here.
                start=""                             } ##Nullifying the variable start here so that in case any line is empty it should not take previous value of it.
' Input_file                                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ awk '/start/ {a=$3} /end/{n++; printf "differance%s : %s\n",n,$3-a}' logs.txt
differance1 : 20
differance2 : 30
```

**How it works:**

- `/start/ {a=$3}`

  Every time we reach a `start` line, we save the start value in variable `a`.
- `/end/{n++; printf "differance%s : %s\n",n,$3-a`

  Every time we reach an `end` line, we print out the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
    function calcul(){
        split(start, st, ":")   # st[1]=hour, st[2]=minutes, st[3]=seconds
        split(end, en, ":")     # en[1]=hour, en[2]=minutes, en[3]=seconds
        start = st[1] * 3600 + st[2] * 60 + st[3]   # seconds
        end = en[1] * 3600 + en[2] * 60 + en[3]     # seconds   # print en[3] en[2] en[1]
        diff_sec = end - start                      # seconds
        diff=sprintf( "%d:%s", diff_sec/60, diff_sec % 60 ) # format M:S
        start = end = ""
    }
    /^start/ { start = $3 }
    /^end/   { end   = $3; calcul(); print diff_sec, "s  ", diff }
' logs.txt
```

test file

```
cat << end > logs.txt
start_time : 10:30:00
end_time : 10:45:00
start_time : 04:20:00
end_time : 05:20:30
end
```

output

```
900 s   15:0
3630 s   60:30
```